# iPhone 6 plus real device UIScreen mainScreen size strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6-plus

When I use the `[UIScreen mainScreen]` to test for the Xcode 6 simulator, the size seems to be correct.

With iPhone 6 size: `375 * 667` and iPhone 6 plus: `414 * 739`.

But when I test `[UIScreen mainScreen]` in real iPhone 6 plus device, result shows that:

```
(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen]

<UIScreen: 0x12ce03f30; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x178039ae0; size = 1125.000000 x 2001.000000>>`
```

But when you test for scale, it will output `3.0` on real iPhone 6 plus device. So, is there any problem there?

Comment: have you add Launch image in your project?

Comment: yes, i fixed it. becasue i did not add the right lauch image. sorry

Answer (score 11):

That's because you set "Settings > Display & Brightness > View" to "Zoomed". If you changed it to "Standard", you'll get 414 * 739.

Comment: Is there a "Settings > Display & Brightness > View" on the Simulator?